# How to fix apps not knowing their accessibility is enabled on Android Go?

Tags: 9.0-pie, accessibility, android-go

I have an Itel A56 running Android 9 (Go edition) and I decided to install an auto clicker app to help automate some things. I finished downloading the app and it asks me to enable accessibility and I do, but when I go back to the app, it tells me that I have to enable accessibility. I go back to settings and the accessibility is still on for the app.

I thought maybe it was a mistake or something, so I put it off and on again, but the app still tells me I need to enable accessibility. I tried putting it off and on many times, and it still wouldn't work. It's as if the app doesn't know its accessibility is enabled.

What is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Hello. Provide us the link of the app.

Comment: Also, could you explain more on which accessibility option and possibly take a screenshot of it? Android Go is known to have fewer features due to memory constraint, so it might be related.

Answer (score 1):

General troubleshooting  : force stop the app, then turn off its accessibility, then open app again and grant accessibility again.

By the way, accessibility issues are known with Android Go editions ; I would suggest you to take this issue to the app developer rather. An email would do it.

Go to play store> that app> scroll down to find contact details

Answer (score 1):

I also use itel A56. It doesn't support auto clickers. The problem is from the phone itself and not the app. I recommend you change your phone because other phones support it.